# Showing that the inverse of the perturbation of a compact operator by a bounded operator remains compact.

Tags: functional-analysis, compact-operators

The title says it all. If we have a Hilbert space $H$, then if $B\in \mathcal B(H)$, $L$ is a linear operator that is not necessarily bounded, $L^{-1}$ is compact, and $0\in \rho(L)\cap\rho(L+B)$, then show $(L+B)^{-1}$ is compact.
Some ideas I had was to appeal to the fact that $K(H)$ (set of compact operators on $H$) is a two-sided ideal, but everything I tried only worked if $L$ was bounded (For example, I wanted to try the inverse bounded theorem).
Any thoughts?

Comment: In this setting, $L^{-1}$ bounded does not imply $L$ bounded: $L$ is not defined on all of $H$ but only on a subspace.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Right, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $(L+B)^{-1} = (I+L^{-1}B)^{-1} L^{-1}$.

EDIT: Further hint: the product of a bounded operator and a compact operator is compact.

FURTHER EDIT: What does the Fredholm alternative say about $(I + L^{-1} B)^{-1}$?

Comment: Right, I tried that factoring and then simplified it to $$(I+L^{−1}B)^{−1}L^{−1}=(L^{-1}(L+B))^{-1}L^{-1}$$ so that I could apply the inverse bounded theorem to $L^{-1}(L+B)$ before realizing that it can only work if $L$ is bounded. Or, if I may ask, what are you hinting at using it for? Am I on the right track at least?

Comment: I already mentioned that I wanted to eventually appeal to the fact that the set of compact operators form a two sided ideal. In your first hint we then have $L^{-1}B$ is compact and added to the identity yields that $I+L^{-1}B$, but as you previously said, there is no guarantee that just because $A$ is bounded that $A^{-1}$ is bounded. I understand wanting to say as little as possible so as to help me do it myself, but thus far, you have reiterated my ideas to me. Can you please give me a more constructive hint that does not reveal the answer, but that gives me so insight to solve the problem?